# Register password field is autofilled

Tags: html, autocomplete, passwords

So on my homepage I have a split layout with the left side being a "register a new account" and the right side being "log in to your existing account".  It has been working fine until recently.  I was setting up phpmyadmin and set a password to my root account which was "12345".  Now for some reason both the register and login password fields are being auto filled  with 12345 I assume.  It's hidden with the password dots so I can't be for sure but its 5 characters long.  When I load the page it looks really weird.  I have never seen firefox auto fill a register forms password field.  wouldn't that defeat the whole "use a different password for each account" principle?  How can I prevent at the very least the register form password field from being auto filled?  BTW I have deleted all firefox history and saved passwords etc etc.. but it still loads with the passwords auto completed.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I prevent at the very least the register form password field from being auto filled?

Use the [`autocomplete` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) in the password input:

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
```